# Chandelier Wiring (Potential Mislabel)

Tags: electrical, wiring, neutral, ground

[image]

[image]

I unboxed a chandelier today and found the pre capped and labeled wiring that in this picture (if you look carefully one on the left has a small white thread on it, one on the right a small green thread, one in the middle with out thread).

My concern is that the company mislabeled the wiring with the stickers they used. If you go off the stickers they claim the wiring with the white thread is Live, and the one with the green thread is Neutral, and the one without thread is the Ground.

However, based on my limited knowledge wouldn't the green threaded wire be the ground, the white threaded neutral, and the other the live wire? I'm also used to seeing copper, is this just tinned copper?

What do others think? And would I get shocked if I wire it according to their stickers, and they are in fact wrongly labeled.

Comment: Is this a fixture with sockets for bulbs or does it have integrated LEDs?

Comment: Does it have a listing from UL, CSA or ETL? (recognized testing labs) ... note that most mail-order stuff doesn't because it's actually from faraway places via free-trade-zone drop ship warehouses such as Amazon Fulfillment.  Also is there writing on the side of the wires, and can you say what it is? (seeing if the wire insulation is a certified type).

Comment: When connecting it up you do turn off the breaker so no shock risk.  If mislabel then the breaker should trip when turning it back on.  A simple test with a multi-meter should allow you to see where those wires are connected in the light.

Comment: @crip659 The big catch is that there are at least 2 miswires that will *not* result in a trip: Hot/Neutral reverse and Neutral/Ground reverse. If the fixture uses bulbs then both can be checked very easily.

Comment: Its a mail order from Serena and Lily. Assembled in Philippines, although wiring likely Chinese. Says UL Certified (will add picture). On wire casing it reads the following: UL E333667 SVT 3X18AWG (0.824mm) 300v VW-1

DONGGUAN R&G

Comment: UL File E333667 is only for the cable, not for the entire fixture. UL File 231688 (from the label in your pic) is for "Incandescent Surface-mounted Luminaires" made by "PAUL-YU INDUSTRIAL CORP" in Taipei, Taiwan. The listing is in UL category IEZR, which covers "Ceiling-mounted luminaires include cord-, stem-, chain- and cable-suspended luminaires, in addition to outlet box-mounted luminaires". So it's *possible* that this is a UL listed product...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key diagnostic question: *Is this a fixture with sockets for bulbs or does it have integrated LEDs?*

If this is a fixture with integrated LEDs then there is no super-easy way to verify the wiring, except possibly for ground (if there is a metal case, it should show continuity with the ground wire).

If this is a fixture with traditional Edison-base bulb sockets (doesn't matter whether small chandelier size or large "regular" size) then:

- Neutral wire - Should show continuity only to the large cylindrical threaded part of the socket
- Hot wire - Should show continuity only to the button in the center of the socket
- Ground wire - Should show continuity only to metal parts of the fixture (and not the socket itself)

For an explanation, [watch this video, starting at 5:54](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Q5wYV3flKI)

If any of this is wrong, send it back. Yes, they could "fix" it, but any if any of the three wires is incorrect - whether via wrong labeling or design or manufacturing flaws - that is a sign of horrendous quality control. Mistakes *can* happen, but there are some other red flags here, so if there is an actual proven defect, back it goes.

Comment: Bulb socket. Picture added. Its a mail order from Serena and Lily. Assembled in Philippines, although wiring likely Chinese. On wire casing it reads the following: UL E333667 SVT 3X18AWG (0.824mm) 300v VW-1 DONGGUAN R&G

Comment: Check the wires as I described. That will tell you how to hook it up. If built properly it could be fine. 18 awg seems small but is actually common for lighting inside the fixture.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   Have a 5HP 240v motor that uses 18g(might be 16g) inside the connection housing on the motor.

Comment: @crip659 windings for a 5HP 240HP motor are probably around 17ga, give or take depending on the design, at least based on the few I've torn apart over the years.

Comment: Thanks @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact . They had labeled the wiring wrong. Was able to confirm b/c of your instructions and get the light up.